# How to set options to ng (Angular) in IntelliJ Run Configuration?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I have a IntelliJ Run Configuration to start up my Angular App. Command is set to "run" and Scripts to "start", when starting it, it will start "ng serve". What do Command and Script mean? And how can I pass an option to ng? I want to start it on a differnt port, like "ng serve --port 4201".

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/run-debug-configuration-npm.html

Answer (score 4):

You can set the port by setting the Arguments field to `-- --port 4201`.
See the link in Oksanas comment for details.

Comment: Somehow, all I was missing was the additional `--` at the beginning.